# How to Cross-Compiling Rasperry Kernel under Ubuntu

Tags: kernel, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling

can somebody explain me exactly how to cross-compile the linux-rpi-3.8.y raspberry's Kernel using Crosstool-ng-1.15.2? I followed various guides found in internet (elinux.org too) but all seems don't work.
Thank you very much in advice.

Comment: How exactly does it not work? Does the kernel not boot? Does it not compile?

Comment: i tried the procedure with mac following the elinux guide but i received errors in elf.h when i tried to compile it.

Answer (score 0):

See arch/arm/config directory there you'll find `bcmrpi_cutdown_defconfig`

make mrproper

```
ARCH=arm make bcmrpi_cutdown_defconfig
ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=${CROSS_COMPILE} make oldconfig
ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=${CROSS_COMPILE} make
ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=${CROSS_COMPILE} make modules_install INSTALL_MOD_PATH=${CLFS}/boot
```